NX The externalDependency 'webpack-cli' for 'app' could not be found
Upon running nx serve app command, the following error appears:
Watch error: Daemon closed the connection Please rerun the command, which will restart the daemon. If you get this error again, check for any errors in the daemon process logs found in: /{pathtoproject}/.nx/cache/d/daemon.log
When checking the log as the error points, it shows:
The externalDependency 'webpack-cli' for 'app' could not be found
Couldn't find the solution yet

Solution:
rm -rf .nx on project root
